# How to make an API call on my server accessible only from one URL

Tags: security, api

I don't know if the title is clear enough, anyway what I need to do is quite simple: I have some content you can access by an API call on my server; this content is user-related so when you request access to it, you must first wait for the owner to authorize you. Since this content will be probably embedded into blog articles or form posts I want it to be accessible only from the URL the user authorized to.

The only way that came to my mind is to check in some secure way where the request is coming from: the problem with this approach is that anybody could create a fake request, using a valid URL but coming from a non-authorized URL actually.

I'm looking for a way to solve this problem, even if this doesn't involve checking the actual URL but using some other approach or whatever. Feel free to ask any questions if this is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With Sessions:**

If you generate a secure token, most languages have libraries to do such a thing, you will have to persist it probably in a session on your server. When you render the page which will access the other content you can add that token to the link/form post/ajax request on the page you wish to be able to access it from.

You would then match that token against the value in the user session if the token doesn't match you return an error of some sort. This solution relies on the security of your session.

**Without Sessions:**

If you don't have sessions to get around server persistance, you can use a trick that amazon s3 uses for security. You would create something like a json string which gives authorization for the next 30 seconds, 5 minutes, whatever is appropriate. It would need to include a timestamp so that the value changes. You would use a secret key on your sever that you combine with the JSON string to create a hash value.

Your request would have to include the JSON string as one request parameter. You would need to base64 encode it or some other means so that you don't run into special characters not allowed over http. The second parameter would be the output of your hash operation.

When you get the request you would decode the JSON string so it was exactly the same as before and hash it with your secret key. If that value matches the one sent with the request it means those are the two values you sent to the page that ultimately requested the content.

**Warnings:**

You need to make sure you're using up to date algorithms and properly audited security libraries to do this stuff, do not try to write your own. There may be other ways around this depending on what context this ultimately ends up in but I think it should be relatively secure. Also I'm not a security expert I would consult one if you're dealing with very sensitive information.